# kendo UI disable/enable required data rule

Tags: kendo-ui

am using Kendo Ui for our MVC project and being very much new to kendoUI stuck with a problem where i need to disable/enable data-validate rule on one of my testbox on the basis of some business rules.

below is the HTML for control :

```
 <pre><input id="txtLastName" type="text" data-tooltip="external" data-tooltip-text="tooltipdemotext" class="form-control k-textbox" data-validate="true" data-rule-message="Last Name cannot be blank" data-rule-name="required" placeholder="Enter Last Name" /></pre>
```

Could someone please help me in this.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Have you tried doing this through jQuery at all? This would seem sensible to me. Alternatively if using Mvc 5.2 or flavour of that you could use some razor in there to do this.

Comment: Thanks David for showing the direction.

Comment: I'm glad my comment helped.

Answer (score 0):

And the answer was a single line statement of Jquery and nothing to do with Kendo

$('#txtLastName').removeAttr('data-validate');

Thanks